# Static typing of Hash table members

Tags: powershell, static-typing

I know PowerShell by default is dynamically typed, which makes a lot of sense for "quick and dirty" one liners and short scripts. But I have started trying to declare variables by type in my long scripts, as it avoids certain bugs. This works fine with regular variables, even when initializing as $null like this `[int]$int = $null`.
However, I also use lots of hash tables to return multiple values from functions, and I would like to use static typing there too. But you can't use a similar approach like this...

```
$hash = @{
    [int]int = $null
    [string]string = $null
}
```

You can cast like this...

```
$hash = @{
    int = [int]$null
    string = [string]$null
}
```

but that still leaves the hash members dynamic, so $hash.int = `'string'` is valid.

I could switch to using custom objects, but I find that rather ugly, v3 type accelerator not withstanding. Sadly I am also pretty much locked in to support for v2, so I feel like hash tables are still the way to go.

So, is there a way to do this in hash tables that I am missing? Or is this the reason for custom objects?

Comment: Hashtables are an made for mapping arbitrary keys to arbitrary values. They're not meant to work like a strict class definition. I doubt that PowerShell supports what you're asking outside custom class definitions.

Comment: @Ansgar That's kind of what I expected. For this and other reasons I should probably consider mandating a PS upgrade, and look at what it would take to automate that as well.